# spring cloud data flow http source client pass credentials

Tags: spring, rest, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a working application  where i get data from a rest end point and dump this to sybase db. Now  i am trying to convert this to spring cloud data flow and defined http as the source and jdbc as the sink. The http end point where my source points to is protected so i need to pass the credentials . I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-modules-http-source) and the allowed params for http source are below .Does this means source has to be an endpoint ?If not how i can achieve the same?

The http source supports the following configuration properties:

> ```
> http.cors.allow-credentials
> Whether the browser should include any cookies associated with the domain of the request being annotated. (Boolean, default: <none>)
> http.cors.allowed-headers
> List of request headers that can be used during the actual request. (String[], default: <none>)
> http.cors.allowed-origins
> List of allowed origins, e.g. "http://domain1.com". (String[], default: <none>)
> http.mapped-request-headers
> Headers that will be mapped. (String[], default: <none>)
> http.path-pattern
> An Ant-Style pattern to determine which http requests will be captured. (String, default: /)
> server.port
> Server HTTP port. (Integer, default: 8080)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just noticed spring cloud has a httpclient  source where i can configure the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `http` source *requires* a fully qualified URL/route, so it can poll and receive the new payloads that land on the route.

There is multiple `http` source samples in the [SCDF samples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) repo, which you can use as a reference.

Likewise, the `http-client` processor requires a fully qualified URL/route to perform a GET or a POST on a every upstream event from the source.